# Apache is only available from localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, lamp

I've installed LAMP and made my website on localhost but I can't reach it from the internet.
I've already did some port forwarding on my router ( SSH, and 2 game servers ) and every one of them are working fine except the web server.

What do I do wrong?

**OS:** Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Change the port of Apache to 81 or something else.
Many routers doesn't allow port 80 even it's enabled.

Comment: Ok so I added a new port. First I got 404. Then I added a new VirtualHost for the new port and I got the same problem again: Cannot connect to the server, but I can reach it from the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a host name to access the webpage remotely and you recently changed the DNS information, it may not have had enough time to propagate yet.  Try using the IP address instead.

If you're already using the IP address, is your Ubuntu machine a physical box or a virtual machine?  You may need to do additional port forwarding if it's a virtual machine.

Comment: I tried with IP address and I've got a physical box.

Comment: @human374 Could you attempt to access the website from another computer on the same LAN?  That will tell you if access is not available on the network at all, or if the router is the point of failure.